# How to export data from MySQL to Excel(.xlsx) but handling the data before exporting

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to export data from MySQL to xlsx but in my database may have some 0 and 1 instead of real data. 
Let me explain better: There's a column used to set if it's day or night but using 0 to day and 1 to night. When i export using the code bellow, i get a xlsx with these 0 and 1.

Already tried stuff like https://phppot.com/php/database-data-export-to-excel-file-using-php/ and https://artisansweb.net/how-to-export-mysql-database-data-to-excel-using-php/ but i just can't edit what's going to xlsx before sending

```
 $filename = "Export_excel.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    $isPrintHeader = false;
    if (! empty($productResult)) {
        foreach ($productResult as $row) {
            if (! $isPrintHeader) {
                echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
                $isPrintHeader = true;
            }
            echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
        }
    }
```

When the code see a zero, i want to set it to "day"

Comment: Why you can't handle this in select query `select your_table.*,
  (
  CASE

  WHEN table_column = 0 THEN 'day'
  WHEN table_column = 1 THEN 'night'

  END
  ) as table_column
from your_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show specific fields only.

select id,name, ( CASE WHEN table_column = 0 THEN 'day' WHEN table_column = 1 THEN 'night' END ) as table_column from your_table

Output Look Like:

id  name   table_column

1   Lucas  day

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your script creates a tab-separated plain text with Excel as mime-type. **This is not a real Excel File and can get you unexpected results.**

If you want to create a real Excel file, use something like [PHPSpreadsheet](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet).

Despite of that, you can change your SQL Query like [Saji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6838959/saji) recommended in his comment or you can do something like this inside the foreach statement:

```
if($row['header_name'] == 0){
    $row['header_name'] = 'day';
}else{
    $row['header_name'] = 'night';
}
```

Note that you must use the key in the array instead of 'header_name' which is also used as column names in your script.